# How to check for server response in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a response in postman form my php code as follows,

```
   {
   "error_code": 0,
   "message": "Inserted Successfully.",
     "msg": "Inserted successfully."
  }
```

MY ANGULAR CODE,

```
   onSubmit(form:any){
 var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 this.http.post('http://localhost/server/index.php/Profile/insertUser', JSON.stringify(form), { headers: headers})
     .subscribe(
        response => {
            if(response.status === 200){

            }
        }
     )
     }
```

But it is not getting response,can anyone help me how to check the response.
The error is

```
Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Please check your response against your post request in your browser debugger network tab. This exception means that you don't have a valid object to parse it as JSON. jsfiddle will help anyway.

Comment: That means you don't have valid json.

Comment: Where is the mistake,then.

Comment: before parse your response as json object, check if you have response or not. Did you check your browser's network tab, are you getting response against your post call?

Comment: The mistake is probably on the server, because it doesn't return valid JSON. Perhaps some error response.

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually SENDING correct json data TO the server? Inspect the data in you post request to see that JSON.stringify(form) gives send good data

Comment: Hi Gunter ,I am not able to insert data sometimes and I edited my code ,Can you pls check.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JSON paramaters with server side. The Error `Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0` told that the invalid JSON parameters in post call.
Check your `JSON.stringify(form)` JSON values.